# Better to use Python or R to search records in very large table for matching features in FGDB?

Tags: python, arcpy

EDIT: I'm trying to find the best solution, and though I'm only familiar with Python, what I'm trying to do shouldn't be that hard or take that long. I've edited the title to ask about options using R or other programs.

I am working on the following challenge in ArcGIS 10.1 on a 64bit computer with Python 2.7.

- I have a table with three fields: ID#, "Revenue" and "Live" - **and 2.1
  million records.**
- I am attempting to pull feature classes from a fGDB by matching it's
  name with the ID# in this table, add two fields to the FC, and
  populate those fields with Revenue and Live data value.
- My script includes a layers and layers of for-loops, if-statements,
  and Search Cursors. Although it worked in a small test batch, it is
  taking forever with the real data, because it is searching 2.1
  million records.
- I've included my script below, which works - and also shows my logic
  flow, which is where I need guidance...

**What is best strategy when comparing/matching a very long list of records to a set of feature classes?**

```
import arcpy
import sys
import os

#Read through DBF. 
#For each record, locate it in fGDB and add fields REVENUE and LIVE

# Use searchCursor to find ID and REV value and LIVE value
#fc = #ID by the APR16ID

fields = ["APR16_ID","REVENUE", "LIVE"]

workspace = "C:\\FILE\\"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace

#Table of values to append to each FC in the fGDB
table = "C:\\FILE\\FinalTest.gdb\\AUG_REV_BY_APRID" 

#DIRECTORYPATH = the fGDB that has the FeatureClasses that are to have data appended to them. 

directorypath = workspace + "DON_d2.gdb" 

#Use searchcursor to determine APR16_ID...

cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, fields) 
for row in cursor:
        fc = str("don_d2_"+"{0}".format(row[0]))
        print fc
        RevVAL = str(row[1])
        print RevVAL
        LiveVAL = str(row[2])
        print LiveVAL

        for dirpath, dirnames, fgdb in arcpy.da.Walk(directorypath,
                                                     datatype="FeatureClass",
                                                     type="Polygon"):
            for donut in fgdb:
                if str(donut)==str(fc):
                    print donut + " : this is the same as " + fc

                    ##Append data to donuts_d2
                    d2_fc = workspace+"DON_d2.gdb\\"+fc
                    arcpy.AddField_management(d2_fc, "REVENUE", "FLOAT")
                    arcpy.AddField_management(d2_fc, "LIVE", "FLOAT")
                    arcpy.GetMessages()

                    #new SearchCursor for that feature
                    dons = arcpy.UpdateCursor(d2_fc, fields)
                    for don in dons:
                        don.setValue("REVENUE",RevVAL)
                        don.setValue("LIVE",LiveVAL)
                        dons.updateRow(don)
                        arcpy.GetMessages()
                else:
                    pass
```

Comment: If you have access to it, always use the data access module. Unless you are debugging, you don't need all those print statements. Also, you are making some unnecessary casts to str().

Comment: Paul is correct, 2.1 million string casts and comparisons is unnecessary and will slow down your program quite a bit if you have actually implemented this into your program. 

However, this isn't the major issue here. The major issue is that you are parsing 2.1 million records, far more than you need to solve this problem. There is little you can do on the GIS side to improve what is going on here. What you need is an efficient search/sort algorithm to carry out this massive table parse. That means this question is more suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Paul - that's great input, thank you. Can you point to the unnecessary str()? I had trouble getting the first SearchCursors to work and produce the variables RevVAL and LiveVAL, and the str(row[1]) method seemed to be the only solution. I'd appreciate the correction, since my other research didn't make the correct syntax clear.

Comment: @Conor - thank you, and if you or others can tell me how, I'll be glad to migrate this question to Stack Overflow (or I'll just copy and paste it in...)

Comment: At the minimum, `fc = str("don_d2_"+"{0}".format(row[0]))` is a strange implementation. Try `"don_d2_{0}".format(row[0])`. You are casting fc again to a string later.

Comment: Is it possible to treat this like a pure DB problem and just join the tables with the ID?

Comment: @SharonB: Only the mods can move questions. I've flagged the question to be moved to Stack Overflow. When a mod sees the flag it will be moved. Regarding the str() casting... is the length of the ID# field fairly short? (6 or 7 vs 20 characters)? You may be better off simply comparing both ID#'s as integers instead of casting them to strings. Again, this probably isn't the bottleneck of your program, the number of rows is.

Comment: @tomfumb - I didn't think so at first, because the format of the ID in the CSV table is different from the format of the ID of each FC in the FGDB. For example, in the CSV the ID # is in the format APR16_XXX  - that record needs to be matched by the ID# to one of several FC in the fGDB, their names are in a different format: don_d2_APR16_XXX. Each FC then needs the new fields added, then the populate the FC with values from the CSV. It's  unfortunately not a simple Join - but I'm open to other ideas.

Comment: @Conor: Comparing the IDs at integers might work, but the FC names are in the format "don_d2_APR16_XXXX" with the XXXX being the number in question. I think I could still compare them with a ID.split(_) command, and pull out the ID # itself to compare....however you are right, it doesn't address the main issue of the large CSV....